# SAPUI5 Busy Indicator - Change standard color?

Tags: colors, uicolor, sapui5, busyindicator

I am using SAP_GOLDREFLECTION theme (cant change it) but I dont want a "golden busy indicator" - is it possible to change its color?

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" type="text/javascript"
  src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons, sap.viz, sap.m, sap.ui.ux3"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_goldreflection">
</script>
```

using:

```
sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.show(0);
...
sap.ui.core.BusyIndicator.hide();
```

Thanks

Comment: You should define your style after the bootstrapping since this will override your style eventually.

Comment: I dont get it running, dont know whats wrong, If I put it after the bootstrap, my complete application does not load any more... flow should be bootstrap, css, view, content - right?

Comment: Maybe it is just a copy/paster mistake but it seems your `<style>`  has no closing tag.

Comment: I´ve added a JS Bin example to my answer. Maybe this helps you finding the error.

Comment: thank you, seems to be working in JSBin, so I will find my mistake eventually ;)

Comment: I think its IE11, using your JSbin in IE11 also results in "no color change" ... any idea?

Comment: I´m afraid the BusyIndicator is generally working different in IE. At least in IE10 there´s no animation. Haven´t tested it in IE11 so far.

Comment: there's an animation in IE10 and IE11, but my css-override does not work for both of them, it seems like IE does not allow the new css code, got any further ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at the CSS-Class `sapUiBusy` which contains the default gold color and override it with your own.

Your CSS-class looks good. I tested it and it works for me. Obviously it´s not included correctly. You could include your CSS in your index.html like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
.sapUiBusy {
    ...
}
</style>
```

Here´s a simple [JS Bin example](http://jsbin.com/bopakulaqe/1/edit?html,output).

Of course it´s also possible (and even better) to put it in a CSS file.

Keep in mind to clear/disable the browser cache!

Comment: where do I find the original class? Thanks Tim! (I opened my application in IE, went to library.css but there's no class sapUiBusy inside...)

Comment: Easiest way to find it is to use the console while your application is running (or in your case 'loading'). In Chrome you can right click the BusyIndicator and check the corresponding CSS-classes. To override it just create a new CSS-class with the same name in your application, copy paste the original content from the console and adapt it to your needs. So there´s no need to find the source code location of the original CSS-class.

Comment: If you want to find it in the sources you should be able to find it in: `sap/ui/core/themes/sap_goldreflection/library.css`.

Comment: I try to change from the orange to a dark red (http://www.color-hex.com/color/990000) .. therefore I tried the css class, see my updated answer, but it does not work, can you help?

Comment: i updated my index.html in the answer, is there an error somewhere?

Comment: @zyrex You should define your style after the UI5 bootstrapping since this will override your style eventually.